# Not() belongs wrong table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using go version go1.10.3 linux/amd64 and mysql 5.7.

Need to runnable with GORM's docker compose config or please provides your config.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    var err error

     db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "gorm:gorm@tcp(localhost:9910)/gorm?charset=utf8&parseTime=True")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.LogMode(true)
}

type Res {
    Id int  `gorm:"column:id"`
    age int  `gorm:"column:age"`
}

func main() {
        var result []Res
    db.Table("A").Select("A.id,A.age").Joins("left join B on A.id=B.id").
        Where("A.age=28").
       Not("B.id", []{2,3,4,5}).
       Scan(&result)
       fmt.Printf("%v", result)
}
```

The sql log is:

> select A.id,A.age from A left join B on A.id=B.id where a.age=28 and A.B.id not in(2,3,4,5)

As can be seen, the not operation is appended for the table A (`A.B.id not in ...`). How can it be appended to table B (`B.id not in ...`)?

Comment: You're clearly connecting to a MySQL DB, why are you importing all of the dialects? Remove all dialect imports except for `_ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as per my comment: You're only using `mysql` as a DB, and yet you're importing all the dialect packages (which do call their respective init functions. These functions register callbacks that are dialect-specific (e.g. the init func in [the MsSQL package](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/dialects/mssql/mssql.go#L37)). Remove all the dialects you're not using from your imports:

```
// remove lines that I've commented out here...
import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    // _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"
     _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    // _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
    // _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)
```

You could move the `NOT IN` part of the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN` condition based off of [the documentation](http://doc.gorm.io/crud.html#joins).

I'd also check any errors that you may encounter, they might give you more debug information on top of the log:

```
err := db.Table("A").Select("A.id,A.age").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN B on A.id =  B.id AND B.id NOT IN (?)", []int{2, 3, 4, 5}).
    Where("age = ?", 28).
    Scan(&result).Error
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fatalf("Failed to execute query: %+v", err)
}
fmt.Prinln(result)
```

Comment: yes, i did it finally,too ，i was confused by the given method Not()

Comment: Given that this is the answer that you eventually went for, would you mind marking it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

resolved

use

```
Where("B.id not in(?)", [] {2,3,4,5}) instead of Not()
```

anybody has a better idea?